# Web developer has become uncooperative, what should we do to rescue our site?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

What can an individual or a company do if the web designer who has designed their website becomes completely uncooperative?

In our case

1. He refuses to meet with us for discussions.
2. He refuses to give us training on the effective use and management
   of the website he has designed for us (and has been paid in full
   for) despite this training being part of the original contract.
3. Last year he disappeared for a number of months ,refused to answer
   emails or phobe calls and was totally unavailable to help us
4. He refuses to give us the details of the hosting of our website.

We have totally lost faith in this arrogant and unreasonable guy and would like to break off all relationships with him but ,it appears, he's got us over a barell

Comment: What does the contract say? If you post the url we can help you find the hosting site.

Comment: Is the website hosted in a third part server? do you own the website hosting or at least the hosting or  domain name is registered in your name?

if so you could try and contact the hosting company

Comment: I think you should post a question asking 1) how you find out where your site is hosted and 2) How to find out who registered the domain and where it's hosted, you'll get an answer - this question isn't a good fit for us as it's a legal issue.